# Why does `find . -type d -not -perm 775` print out directories with `rwxr-xr-x` permissions?

Tags: find

I want to find all directories without a specific set of permissions. As seen from the below image, `find` prints out directories that should not be listed.

Can someone describe why?

[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and use [code block] instead

Comment: Also `rwxr-xr-x` is 755, so that is not 775, so this should be as expected, right?

Comment: Please don't post images of text, for a few reasons, including the fact that posting text as text makes it easier for people to help you as they can copy the text off the question instead of typing it by hand. See: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text

Comment: Now, I wonder, what exactly do you mean with "directories without a specific set of permissions"? And have you checked what the man page says of `-perm`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `find` command is doing exactly what you told it to, as @muru says in his comment. `drwxr-xr-x` is mode 755 (0755 if you want to be pedantic about it), which should be printed because you're looking for permissions that are not 775.

Additional technical detail:
The mode of a file is a four-digit octal number. The first digit, which is often left off if it is zero (0), is for special permissions bits. Set-UID (SUID) has a value of four (4), Set-GID (SGID) a value of two (2), and sticky a value of one (1). Those values are added when that particular bit is present to give the first digit value.

The next three digits derive from owner, group, and other permissions respectively. Read permission has a value of four (4), write a value of two (2), and execute a value of one (1). Those values are added to produce the owner/group/other digits in the octal permission representation.

It is also sometimes represented as a five-digit value, the first of which is always a zero (0) to designate an octal value, similar to hexadecimal values usually being preceeded by a '0x' to designate it as a hexadecimal. Both the leading octal zero and the special bit digits are often left off, though they used to be more regularly used.

Comment: Might be worth pointing the `-perm u=rwx,g=rx,o=rx`, `-perm u=rwx,go=rx`  or `-perm a=rx,u+w` alternatives. Also note the `!` as the standard equivalent of BSD's `-not` (also available in GNU and some others these days).